# No module named 'torch' or 'torch.C'

Tags: pytorch

Would appreciate an explanation like I'm 5 simply because I have checked all relevant answers and none have helped.

I have installed Python.
I have installed Pycharm.
I have installed Anaconda.
I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio.
I have **not** installed the CUDA toolkit.

In Anaconda, I used the commands mentioned on Pytorch.org (06/05/18)

```
conda install pytorch -c pytorch
pip3 install torchvision
```

Both have downloaded and installed properly, and I can find them in my Users/Anaconda3/pkgs folder, which I have added to the Python path.

Trying to enter

```
import torch
```

in the Python console proved unfruitful - always giving me the same error,

> No module named 'torch'

I have also tried using the Project Interpreter to download the Pytorch package. It worked for numpy (sanity check, I suppose) but told me to go to Pytorch.org when I tried to install the "pytorch" or "torch" packages.

When trying to use the console in PyCharm, pip3 install codes (thinking maybe I need to save the packages into my current project, rather than in the Anaconda folder) return me an error message saying

> torch-0.4.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this
>   platform.

The same message shows no matter if I try downloading the CUDA version or not, or if I choose to use the 3.5 or 3.6 Python link (I have Python 3.7)

Currently the closest I have gotten to a solution, is manually copying the "torch" and "torch-0.4.0-py3.6.egg-info" folders into my current Project's lib folder.
However, when I do that and then run "import torch" I received the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
>
> module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\Pytorch_2\venv\lib\site-packages\torch__init__.py",
>
> line 78, in
>
> from torch._C import *
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.2\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 19, in do_import
>
> module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'

Answer (score 9):

```
pip uninstall torch
```

then
`pip install torch` worked for me.

Comment: Not worked for me! I don't think simply uninstalling and then re-installing the package is a good idea at all. There should be some fundamental reason why this wouldn't work even when it's already been installed!

Comment: @inverted_index `torch` is a rather big package. I ran out of disk space mid installation, which a reinstallation helped fix. I'm not saying this is what caused OP's issue, but it did solve my specific situation

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem because I updated my python from 3.5 to 3.6 yesterday. I think the connection between Pytorch and Python is not correctly changed. Thus, I installed Pytorch for 3.6 again and the problem is solved.
Check the install command line here[[1](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)].

Comment: Indeed, I too downloaded Python 3.6 after some awkward mess-ups... in retrospect what could have happened is that I download pytorch on an old version of Python and then reinstalled a newer version.

Perhaps that's what caused the issue. I'll have to attempt this when I get home :)

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same problem... All I did to fix this problem was to change the interpreter in my Visual Studio Code to ***Python 3.11.4 ('Base')*** this python version is the version used in Anaconda Navigator then I opened my **Anaconda Navigator** and I launched the Jupyter then I created a new file then I type pip install torch. And now my problem is solved