# pytorch: ModuleNotFoundError exception on windows 10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I have installed pytorch using

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

In the jupyter notebook, the 'import torch' fails:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._C'

Comment: May you just Check out below link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203945/no-module-named-torch-or-torch-c

Comment: 1. PyTorch installed locally works
2. The resolution included following steps:
a. Use pip instead of conda 
b.     c:\Users\joepareti\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\Scripts\pip.exe install torch==1.4.0+cpu torchvision==0.5.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
c. the pip version is critical: on my system there are different pip versions. A previous installation using a different pip version completed normally, but torch could not be imported